# Okhttp newBuilder per request

Tags: java, okhttp

Trying to implement okhttp the correct way. I understand the OkHttpClient must be shared (Singleton), however I am not clearly understanding `.newBuilder();`

***Sample Code:***

```java
// Instantiated once
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(readTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(200, connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        .build(); 

public static String makeRestCall(String url, String data, Interceptor customInterceptor) {
    // Questions on the line below
    OkHttpClient newClient = client.newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(customInterceptor)
        .build();

    ....
    try (Response response = newClient.newCall(httpRequest).execute()) {
            final ResponseBody body = response.body();
            return body.string();
    }
    return "NO_DATA";
}
```

I have a few questions around `.newBuilder()`

1. When we add a new interceptor to `newClient`, does the original `client` also get updated by reference?
2. Classes calling `makeRestCall` decide on what customInteceptor they need. Is it ok to call `.newBuilder()` for every request?

I have been searching the documentation and playing with the implementation but haven't had clarity on the above.

Any assistance/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When we add a new interceptor to newClient, does the original client also get updated by reference?

No, the original is unchanged. Its configuration is immutable.

> 2. Classes calling makeRestCall decide on what customInteceptor they need. Is it ok to call .newBuilder() for every request?

Absolutely. That operation is cheap because it only duplicates the configuration. Resource-intensive stuff like the connection pool and cache are not duplicated.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Helps a lot. Would you say Okhttp uses the prototype design pattern (But with some shared components)?

Comment: Yeah! Great observation.